# Fabricjs: how to get the starting point of a path?

Tags: fabricjs

Is there any built-in method in fabricjs that returns the coordinates of the starting point of a path ? I do not need the coordinates of the bounding rectangle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To get the starting point you have to extract the point and calculate its actual position on canvas. As of fabric 1.6.0 you have all functions to do that, for the previous version you need a bit more logic:

example path:

```
var myPath = new fabric.Path('M 25 0 L 300 100 L 200 300 z');
```

point:

```
var x = myPath.path[0][1];
var y = myPath.path[0][2];
var point = {x: x, y: y};
```

Logic:

1) calculate path transformation matrix:
needs: path.getCenterPoint(); path.angle, path.scaleX, path.scaleY, path.skewX, path.skewY, path.flipX, path.flipY.

```
  var degreesToradians = fabric.util.degreesToradians,
      multiplyMatrices = fabric.util.multiplyTransformMatrices,
      center = this.getCenterPoint(),
      theta = degreesToRadians(path.angle),
      cos = Math.cos(theta),
      sin = Math.sin(theta),
      translateMatrix = [1, 0, 0, 1, center.x, center.y],
      rotateMatrix = [cos, sin, -sin, cos, 0, 0],
      skewMatrixX = [1, 0, Math.tan(degreesToRadians(path.skewX)), 1],
      skewMatrixY = [1, Math.tan(degreesToRadians(path.skewY)), 0, 1],
      scaleX = path.scaleX * (apth.flipX ? -1 : 1),
      scaleY = path.scaleY * (path.flipY ? -1 : 1),
      scaleMatrix = [path.scaleX, 0, 0, path.scaleY],
      matrix = path.group ? path.group.calcTransformMatrix() : [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0];
  matrix = multiplyMatrices(matrix, translateMatrix);
  matrix = multiplyMatrices(matrix, rotateMatrix);
  matrix = multiplyMatrices(matrix, scaleMatrix);
  matrix = multiplyMatrices(matrix , skewMatrixX);
  matrix = multiplyMatrices(matrix , skewMatrixY);
```

// at this point you have the transform matrice.

Now take the rendering path process:

the canvas is transformed by matrix, then the point of path ar drawn with an offset that you can find in path.pathOffset.x and path.pathOffset.y.

So take your first point, subtract the offset.

```
point.x -= path.pathOffset.x;
point.y -= path.pathOffset.y;
```

Then

```
var finalpoint = fabric.util.transformPoint(point, matrix);
```

In new fabric 1.6.0 all the logic is in a function, you can just run:

var matrix = path.calcTransformMatrix(); and then proceed with transform Point logic.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the Path.path property. It is a 2D array containing an element for each path command.  The second array holds the command in the first element e.g. 'M' for move, the following elements contain the coordinates.

```
var myPath = new fabric.Path('M 25 0 L 300 100 L 200 300 z');

var startX = myPath.path[0][1];
var startY = myPath.path[0][2];
```

Comment: I saw the path array of points but I need the starting point with the scale and translate parameters applied.

Comment: For my project I find it best to use Fabric.js as the presentation layer and calculate the required values in my logic layer.